# How to disable ,hiding options from dopdown after selection

Tags: angular, primeng

Am working on angular application with primeng. I need to stop hiding the options of menu dropdown after selecting an option!

```
<p-menu onchange="onSelected" [showTransitionOptions]="'0ms'" [hideTransitionOptions]="" #menu [popup]="true" 
[model]="items"></p-menu>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-fw fa-list" label="Sort" 
(click)="menu.toggle($event)"></button>


  onSortingSelected() {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

How to solve this? I need to click on multiple selection options one at a time without hiding the option list!

Comment: Hi, I think would be easier to get help if you can provide a [mre]

Comment: yeah please refer this link will get an idea, i want to implement this menu 

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menu

1.on click show button option should display. 2. but after selecting an option from option list, the option list should stay and donot disappear!

Comment: i hope the question is clear please up vote the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the PrimaNG code

```js
    itemClick(event, item: MenuItem) {
        if (item.disabled) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        if (!item.url) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if (item.command) {
            item.command({
                originalEvent: event,
                item: item
            });
        }

        if (this.popup) {
            this.hide();
        }
    }
```

Looks like there's no way to change that behaviour.

One possible solution is to write your component inheriting from the PrimeNG one and override the itemClick implementation

I never tried but .... there's this [article](https://alligator.io/angular/component-inheritance/) that might help

Comment: yeah understood! thanks for the help @Massimo actually is it time consuming to implement this functionality by extending? just asking ...!

Comment: as I said I never had to do so I'm only guessing, depends on your needs but .... doesn't look like super hard